# How to get last value from VLookup?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, lookup

I know this has been asked a number of times, but I haven't quite found an answer that fits my situation. I've tried using INDEX and the TRUE value, but it doesn't seem to working for me. I also tried changing the columns (DATE, then ITEM and COST), but to no avail.

I am using GOOGLE SHEETS.

The workbook has two sheets, this one is called Reference. The one it calls is called Sales. The data is UNSORTED by item, but is sorted by date, though duplicate instances may exist. I am using this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sales!A:C,3,false)
```

It works, but it calls the FIRST value. I need the LATEST value. It needs to go through the entire COLUMN to search for this value, then return the corresponding (latest) value on the third column. Both sheets have ITEM column; the purpose of Reference is to check if there is a match for the item existing on the Sales sheet and, if it's there, refer to the latest value "COST". Because numerous instances of ITEM and COST are in sales with differing values, I need to call up the latest number.

In addition, I have another formula that calls data from another sheet, in another workbook, that does virtually the same thing:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/URL/","Sales!A:C"),3,false)
```

Again, it works at getting the value I need, just not the LATEST value. The sheet is formatted like this:

```
(SALES)
ITEM     DATE     COST
A2       B2       C2
A3       B3       C3
```

The reference sheet is like so:

```
(REFERENCE)
ITEM     LOOKUP
A2       B2
A3       B3
```

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using Google Sheet please tag it in the question, and not Excel as you've done

Comment: Apologies. When I did that, it was coming up as "Google" and then "Sheets". From my searches, it *appeared* that the formulas were shared, at least in terms of index, lookup, match and others.

Comment: share a copy (sample) of your sheet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

all you need to do is sort it in descending order either based on dates or rows (based on your preferences / needs)

example:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, SORT(Sales!A:C, 1 +N("1st column contains dates"), 0 +N("descending")), 3, )
```

Comment: This didn't work for me at first, but after looking up the documentation on SORT, I was able to come up with a solution based on your answer: =VLOOKUP(A2, SORT(Sales!A:C, 2, false), 3, )  THANK YOU! MARKED AS ANSWERED. <3

Answer (score -1):

By Definition, VLOOKUP would return the 1st value matching your search criteria, which leaves you with two options:
The Lazy one: Sort the other Sheet by Date Newest to Oldest (that what I would do)
Alternatively, use [XLOOKUP](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-xlookup-function) (if your excel version supports that).

Comment: Please note OP using google-sheet and google-sheet doesn't s support `XLOOKUP()`.

Comment: @Harun24HR, the question tags Excel, not google sheet... The sort order by date works in Google sheet just as well

Comment: @Hila DG I tagged Excel since my searches came up with information shared between the two. I didn't come up with any differences, though they may exist. So, indeed, it is Google Sheets. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also, just to add, the sheet Sales is sorted by Date already. This is a transactional record which sometimes has more than one instance of the same data for one date. However, when using index, lookup and vlookup on Reference, I wasn't able to get the latest info, even when that didn't happen. Obviously, that doesn't mean it can't happen, it just means I haven't found the answer yet.

Comment: Thank you for adding the tag, @Mirume. This way not only it attracts better answers but also it enables future users to find this question.